# Searching multiple radio button collections in hta

Tags: loops, collections, vbscript, hta

Bellow is a hta/vbs code I wrote to dynamically build a form with radio buttons.

The hta is launched by another vbs script that specifies the amount of radio button (yes/no) collections to create.

The issue I'm having is in the `Sub Write` in the loop `While x <= ItemListSize`. I can't get the `For Each objRadio in RadioButton&x` to check multiple collections.

I've tried what is present and `For Each objRadio in RadioButton[x]`. All of the code works if I change it to the first collection `For Each objRadio in RadioButton1`, but then I'm unable to check all the other collections for `.checked` objects.

I know this code is not very optimized.

```html
<head>
<title>Autonomous Maintenance</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION 
     APPLICATIONNAME="Autonomous Maintenance"
  APPLICATION ID="AutoMaintenance"
  BORDER="thin"
  CAPTION="yes"
  ICON="Am.ico"
  MAXIMIZEBUTTON="no"
  MINIMIZEBUTTON="no"
  SHOWINTASKBAR"no"
  WINDOWSTATE="normal"
  INNERBORDER="yes"
  NAVIGABLE="no"
     SCROLL="no"
  SCROLLFLAT="no"
     SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
  SYSMENU="yes"
  CONTEXTMENU="yes"
  SELECTION="no"
  VERSION="1.0"
>
</head>

<script language="VBScript">
 Dim LogPath
 Dim ItemList
 Dim ItemListSize
 Dim strHTML
 Dim addHeight
 
 arrCommands = Split(AutoMaintenance.commandLine, chr(34))
 LogPath = arrCommands(3)
 ItemList = arrCommands(5)
 ItemList = Split(ItemList, ";")
 ItemListSize = uBound(ItemList)

 If ItemListSize <= 10 Then
  strHTML = strHTML & "<table border='0' >"
  y = 1
  x = 0
  While y <= ItemListSize
   strHTML = strHTML & "<tr><td width='120' align='left' valign='middle'>"
   strHTML = strHTML & "<input type='radio' name='RadioButton"&y&"' value='"&ItemList(x)&" => Yes'>Yes<input type='radio' name='RadioButton"&y&"' value='"&ItemList(x)&" => No'>No</td>"
   strHTML = strHTML & "<td align='left' valign='middle'>"&ItemList(x)&"</td></tr>"
   y = 1 + y
   x = 1 + x
   
   addHeight = addHeight + 25
  Wend
  strHTML = strHTML & "</table>"
 Else
  If ItemListSize <= 20 Then
  
   strHTML = strHTML & "<table border='0' >"
   y = 1
   x = 0
   While y <= 10
    strHTML = strHTML & "<tr><td width='120' align='left' valign='middle'>"
    strHTML = strHTML & "<input type='radio' name='RadioButton"&y&"' value='"&ItemList(x)&" => Yes'>Yes<input type='radio' name='RadioButton"&y&"' value='"&ItemList(x)&" => No'>No</td>"
    strHTML = strHTML & "<td align='left' valign='middle'>"&ItemList(x)&"</td>"
    y = 1 + y
    x = 1 + x
    IF y <= ItemListSize Then
     strHTML = strHTML & "<td width='50' align='center' valign='middle'></td>"
     strHTML = strHTML & "<td width='120' align='left' valign='middle'>"&"<input type='radio' name='RadioButton"&y&"' value'"&ItemList(x)&" => Yes'>Yes<input type='radio' name='RadioButton"&y&"' value='"&ItemList(x)&" => No'>No</td>"
     strHTML = strHTML & "<td align='left' valign='middle'>"&ItemList(x)&"</td></tr>"
     y = 1 + y
     x = 1 + x
     addHeight = addHeight + 25
    End If
   Wend
   While y <= ItemListSize
    strHTML = strHTML & "<tr><td width='120' align='left' valign='middle'>"
    strHTML = strHTML & "<input type='radio' name='RadioButton"&y&"' value='"&ItemList(x)&" => Yes'>Yes<input type='radio' name='RadioButton"&y&"' value='"&ItemList(x)&" => No'>No</td>"
    strHTML = strHTML & "<td align='left' valign='middle'>"&ItemList(x)&"</td>"
    y = 1 + y
    x = 1 + x
    IF y <= ItemListSize Then
     strHTML = strHTML & "<td width='50' align='center' valign='middle'></td>"
     strHTML = strHTML & "<td width='120' align='left' valign='middle'>"&"<input type='radio' name='RadioButton"&y&"' value='"&ItemList(x)&" => Yes'>Yes<input type='radio' name='RadioButton"&y&"' value='"&ItemList(x)&" => No'>No</td>"
     strHTML = strHTML & "<td align='left' valign='middle'>"&ItemList(x)&"</td></tr>"
     y = 1 + y
     x = 1 + x
     addHeight = addHeight + 25
    End If
   Wend
   strHTML = strHTML & "</table>"
   addWidth = addWidth + 250
  Else
   If ItemListSize > 20 Then
    MsgBox "To many items to verify!"
    window.Close()
   End If
  End If
 End If
 
 Sub Window_Onload  
  window.resizeTo 480 + addWidth,485 + addHeight
  screenWidth = Document.ParentWindow.Screen.AvailWidth
  screenHeight = Document.ParentWindow.Screen.AvailHeight
  posLeft = (screenWidth - 480 - addWidth) / 2
  posTop = (screenHeight - 485 - addHeight) / 2     
        window.moveTo posLeft, posTop
  
  DataArea.InnerHTML = strHTML
 End Sub

 Sub Write
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set oFile = fso.OpenTextFile(LogPath,2,true)
  sTxtArea = document.all("Comments").Value
  Dim sItem()
  ReDim sItem(0)
  x = 1
  y = 0
  While x <= ItemListSize
   Dim Rbutton
   For Each objRadio in RadioButton&x
    If objRadio.checked Then
     sItem(y) = objRadio.value
     EntryFound = "True"
     ReDim Preserve sItem (UBound(sItem) + 1)
    End If
   Next
   x = x + 1
   y = y + 1
  
   If EntryFound <> "True" Then
    MsgBox "Please verify all items."
    Exit Sub
   End IF
  Wend
  
  Answers = Join(sItem, ";")
  oFIle.Write sTxtArea & ";" & Answers
  oFile.close
  window.Close()
 End Sub
 
</script>

<body>
 <body STYLE="font:12 pt arial; color:black; background-color:white"> 
 <div align="center">
 <p>
  <img id = "Logo" alt="MagellanLogo" style="height: 57px; width: 232px" src= "MagellanLogo.jpg" />
  <br>
  <font style="font:15 pt arial black"><Text>Autonomous Maintenance</Text></font>
  <br>
  <Text>Are these items acceptable:</Text><br>
  <br>
  
  <span id ="DataArea"></span>
     
  <br>
  <Text>Comments</Text><br>
  <textarea name="Comments" cols=50 rows=10></textarea>
 </p>
 <p>
  <font style="font:12 pt arial"> Click bellow to complete  </font>
  <br>
  <font style="font:8 pt arial"> By clicking bellow you accept that you have completed the autonomous maintenance. </font>
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Finish" name="run_button" onclick="Write">
 </p>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
For Each objRadio in RadioButton&x  'or similar construction
```

use `Eval` function as follows:

```
For Each objRadio in Eval("RadioButton" & CStr(x))
```

[Poorly documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z5x4094(v=vs.84).aspx) however should work.